# Strategy to kill Developer in Candy Box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I watched a YouTube video where someone killed the Developer. First, he went up to him and melees him using the Scythe. Right before the "Hello" attack hits, he uses and Turtle Potion and Black Hole. He says the Turtle Potion will protect him from the Developer's Black Hole and since he's touching him, the Developer takes 2 Black Holes. I tried the exact same thing but I died. Is there another strategy?

I have:

- Pink Gloves
- Scythe
- 1560 hp
- Knight's Body Armour (Non-enchanted)
- 40% more power

(There is a similar question but i have different stats)

Comment: I read that one but I have different stats.

Comment: The linked question mentions nothing about stats.

Comment: He has more power. Let me double check.

Comment: I didn't read the rest of the answers. Oops! Can someone help delete this question?